# Install GCC 7 on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, gcc, ppa

I'm trying to run a test under GCC 7. According to [How to install gcc-7 or clang 4.0?](https://askubuntu.com/q/859256) on Ubuntu.SE, we can perform the following to install GCC 7 on Ubuntu:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test && apt-get update && apt-get install -y gcc-7
```

The command fails at the install:

```
# apt-get install -y gcc-7
...
E: Unable to locate package gcc-7
```

And trying 7.1:

```
# apt-get install -y gcc-7.1
...
E: Unable to locate package gcc-7.1
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'gcc-7.1'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'gcc-7.1'
```

According to [List all packages from a repository in ubuntu / debian](https://serverfault.com/q/252333/145545) on Server Fault, we can search a particular repo for a package with:

```
# grep ^Package: /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_*_Packages | grep gcc-7
#
```

But I am not sure if the command above is searching `ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r`.

I kind of pieced things together, but they are not working as expected. Either the Ubuntu.SE answer is wrong, the Server Fault search is failing, or I am doing something wrong.

(I don't have a Debain 8 machine available for [gcc-7 package](https://packages.qa.debian.org/g/gcc-7.html), and Fedora 25 appears to lack GCC 7. So I am pretty much stuck with Ubuntu).

What am I doing wrong? Or, how can I install GCC 7?

---

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.10
Release:        16.10
Codename:       yakkety
```

Comment: The `ubuntu-toolchain-r/test` PPA does not appear to provide gcc-7 for Ubuntu 16.10 (Yakkety) - although it does for both 16.04 (Xenial) and 17.04 (Zesty) - as you can see by visiting [“PPA for Ubuntu Toolchain Uploads (restricted)” team](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test) and filtering by series

Comment: Thanks Steeldriver. Expanding the caret labeled *"Technical details about this PPA"* seems to show its available for 16.10. Weird... I think I'll put this bug report on hold until we can find a distro that provides GCC 7.

Comment: The PPA is available for 16.10, but it does not provide the all the same packages - possibly because 16.10 is not an [LTS release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS)

Comment: For those who can't get this to work (like me), also see [How can I undo adding a PPA and installing packages from it?](https://askubuntu.com/q/358625) on Ubuntu Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 7):

To install `gcc-7` on ubuntu you should use this [ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Ejonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/gcc-7.1):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/gcc
sudo apt-get update
```

Then run: `apt-cache search gcc-7`

sample output :

```
gcc-7-base - GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
gcc-7 - GNU C compiler
gcc-7-multilib - GNU C compiler (multilib support)
gcc-7-plugin-dev - Files for GNU GCC plugin development.
gcc-7-test-results - Test results for the GCC test suite
lib32gcc-7-dev - GCC support library (32 bit development files)
libgcc-7-dev - GCC support library (development files)
gcc-7-doc - Documentation for the GNU compilers (gcc, gobjc, g++)
gcc-7-hppa64-linux-gnu - GNU C compiler (cross compiler for hppa64)
gcc-7-locales - GCC, the GNU compiler collection (native language support files)
gcc-7-source - Source of the GNU Compiler Collection
libx32gcc-7-dev - GCC support library (x32 development files)
gcc-7-offload-nvptx - GCC offloading compiler to NVPTX
lib64gcc-7-dev - GCC support library (64bit development files)
```

Install `gcc-7`:

```
sudo apt install gcc-7
```

Comment: Thanks GAD3R. Do you know who jonathonf is? I'm trying to use Ubuntu's gear because its already trusted. Otherwise, I have to jump through the hoops of figuring out who jonathonf is, and determine if he is a trustworthy source.

Comment: Should it work for linaro as well?

Comment: Command is now `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/gcc`, without the trailing -7. You can also get [other GCC versions](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/gcc) from the repo. Don't forget the apt update!

Comment: @Phi Thank you for this update

Answer (score 2):

If you need to setup a test rig with the compiler, then [Fedora 26](http://getfedora.org/en/workstation/) ships with GCC 7.1.

You can also find GCC 7 in [Debian 10/Buster](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianBuster) (Debian 9 with Testing repo enabled). For Debian, you must `apt-get install gcc-7 g++-7`.

For completeness, its not clear which version of the Microsoft compilers support C++17 and `std::byte` (the reason I needed the compiler for testing).

And thanks to GAD3R for his help. The reason I avoided it was I could not establish provenance for some of the PPAs.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 18.04 has both GCC 7 (7.3.0-16ubuntu3, at the moment I am writing this answer) and GCC 8 (8-20180414-1ubuntu2). There isn't anymore the need of adding third-party repositories: Just run `sudo apt-get install gcc-7`.